# Using own symbols for ggplot points, changing legend symbols to match

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a series of data points, for which I need very specific symbols/shapes to represent each Country (it's not actually country but the real group will make no sense - I'm copying an old graph and want to keep the symbols consistent).  There are nine different countries to plot.  The easiest way I've found to do this so far is by coding the symbols I want in the actual dataframe like this:

```
Point    y       x       Country
V      0.316   0.073     UK
P      0.284   0.053     USA
%      0.284   0.061     Germany
+      0.314   0.072     France     
|      0.268   0.075     Spain     
h      0.313   0.0758    Canada
#      0.121   0.0623    Australia
i      0.234   0.0765    India
C      0.213   0.059     Norway
```

and then plotting like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, label = Point, colour = Point)) + geom_text()
```

But this isn't particularly good when it comes to the legend:

[image]

How could I do this so that the Points become the symbols of the legend and then I can have the countries as the labels of the legend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `shape=country` into `aes()` and choose symbols using `scale_shape_manual()`

```
x=rnorm(10,1,2)
y=rnorm(10,1,2)
country=letters[1:10]
data=cbind.data.frame(x,y,country)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,shape=country))+
  geom_point(size=6)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("V","%","µ","@","#","V","%","µ","@","#"))
```

[image]